# Oracle VirtualBox aborted when the host system lock

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed oracle virtual box 4.3.28 in a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 OS in office PC.Thinking of that I will create as a SQL database server so that others can connected to that sql server and do theie work.All goes well and performing well.

but there is one issue which I am facing is when I lock my system or pc then virtual box GUI mode closed and when I re-run the virtual box I found it  in aborted mode.

Please share some knowledge over this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can personally attest that this is not a normal outcome. My VBox VMs do not abort on host lock or sleep events. That said however, often PCs will power down the NIC on sleep, so I suggest you disable hibernate and system sleep on the box  if you want others to access the VM at any time. just have it turn off the monitors, but leave the disks active. make sure the NIC driver does not allow the system to power off the nic on sleep (look at the nic driver in the Device Manager to find the setting). Let us know if that works.

Comment: How are you locking the PC?  What keyboard combination or button do you click?

Comment: Frank I have made the changes as you suggested but nothing help.Still facing the same issue.

Comment: heavyd,I am using combined key (windods and L) to lock my system.